# multiple file upload uploads only single post

Tags: php, mysql, multiple-file-upload

I have the following code for multiple file uploads using php and mysql. But for some reason , if 'n' files are selected, only the last(or 'n'th) file seems to be uploaded..

Here are the respective files:

***HTML***

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
           <div class="form-group">
           <textarea class="form-control" name="postbox" id="pbox"></textarea>
           </div>
           <h5><strong>Add media:</strong></h5>
           <input type="file" name="pfile[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*,audio/*,video/*"><br/>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="psubmit">Post!</button>
          </form>
<div class="posts">
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['postbox'])){
    $ps = escape($_POST['postbox']);
  }
  include_once('includes/uploadfile.php'); ?>
</div>
```

***includes/uploadfile.php***

```
     <?php ob_start();
require_once 'core/init.php';

if(isset($_POST['psubmit']))
    {
        foreach ($_FILES['pfile']['tmp_name'] as $key=>$value)
      {
            $pfname = $_FILES["pfile"]['name'][$key];
            $pftype = $_FILES['pfile']['type'][$key];
            $pfsize = $_FILES['pfile']['size'][$key];
            $pftmploc = $_FILES['pfile']['tmp_name'][$key];
            $pferror = $_FILES['pfile']['error'][$key];
            $blast = explode(".", $pfname);
            $pfextn = end($blast);
            if (!empty($ps) && empty($pfname)) 
            {

                $dbfname = NULL;
                $abc = $get->addPost($a, $ps, $pfname);
                header('location:'.escape($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])); exit;

            }

            else if (!empty($pfname) && !empty($ps))
            {
                //list($width, $height) = getimagesize($pftmploc);

                 if($pfsize > 20971520) 
                { 
                echo "ERROR: Your file was larger than 20 Megabytes in size.";
                unlink($pftmploc);
                exit();
                } 
                else if(!preg_match("/.(gif|jpg|png|mp3|mp4|avi)$/i", $pfname) ) 
                {
                 echo "ERROR: Restricted file format!Kindly stick to these formats alone:gif,jpg,png,mp3,mp4,avi";
                 unlink($pftmploc);
                 exit();
                }
                 else if($pferror == 1) 
                { // if file upload error key is equal to 1
                echo "ERROR: An error occured while processing the file. Try again.";
                exit();
                }
            }

             $dbfname = rand(100000000000,999999999999).$pfname;
            $updir = "ups/posts/";
            $arraymov = array();
            array_push($arraymov, $dbfname);
            $movrslt = move_uploaded_file($pftmploc,$updir.$dbfname);
            if($movrslt != true)
                {
                    echo 'ERROR: File upload failed. Try again!';
                    exit();
                }
          }  
                $abc = $get->addPost($a, $ps, implode(',',$arraymov));
            header('location:'.escape($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])); exit;
     }  
?>
```

***File upload function:***

```
public function addPost($user_id,$status,$file_path){
                $query = $this->_db->prepare("INSERT INTO postsinitial (puid, pstatus, postimg) VALUES (:k, :l, :m)");
                $query->bindValue(':k',$user_id);
                $query->bindValue(':l', nl2br(htmlentities($status, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')));
                $query->bindValue(':m',$file_path);
                $query->execute();
                $rsizes = $query->rowCount();

                 if ($rsizes > 0) {
                  return true;
                  }
                   else
                  {
                   return false;
                  }
            }
```

I've tried to code to insert each file path as a comma-separated array of values so that a user can upload multiple images for only one record in database.This is important!

Tnx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have got the logic wrong. You have to execute move_uploaded_file() within the same foreach() that loops through the $_FILES array.

```
...
echo "ERROR: An error occured while processing the file. Try again.";
            exit();
       }
   }

   move_uploaded_file(...
}
```

What you have done is trying to execute move_uploaded_file() in a separate foreach block using $pftmploc variable as the temporary file path. But since that variable was assigned inside the previous foreach() loop, it represents the last element of the uploaded files array. Thats why you are not getting all the files uploaded.

Comment: tq for ur suggestion...well i tried n have re-edited the question again...kindly check it..bt the thing is , now though the files are being moved, oly one name is being recorded in the db..i want an array of all the image names against a single post_id row in the db for that post..!

Comment: @Vanessa341 thats easy. You have to take out $arraymov = array(); statement out of the foreach() loop. It should be placed just before you start the loop. In this order: 

if(isset($_POST['psubmit']))
{
     $arraymov = array();

     foreach(($_FILES['pfile' ......

Comment: @Vanessa341 Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

The foreach does not look quite right. Try this snippet in your uploadfile.php in place of the foreach part. It builds your loop a little differently, checking the tmp_name to see if the loop should continue.

```
if(isset($_POST['psubmit']))
{
    $imagearray = array();
    for ($i = 0; $_FILES['pfile']['tmp_name'][$i] $i++)
    {
        $pfname = $_FILES["pfile"]['name'][$i];
        $pftype = $_FILES['pfile']['type'][$i];
        $pfsize = $_FILES['pfile']['size'][$i];
        $pftmploc = $_FILES['pfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $pferror = $_FILES['pfile']['error'][$i];
        $blast = explode(".", $pfname);
        $pfextn = end($blast);
        array_push($imagearray, $pfname);
        if (!empty($ps) && empty($pfname)) 
        { ...
```

Comment: tq for ur prompt ans..will try n get back!!

Comment: nope still d same..only the last file s being uploded

Comment: Not really sure. there are elements of your code that are obscured possibly by other code we don't see. For example, what is "$ps"? I do not see where that variable is defined. Also, there are some inconsistencies, like inside one "if" statement which has this criteria: "!empty($pfname) && !empty($ps)", you have another "if" statement with this: "if(empty($ps))" That internal one will never be executed. I can only assume that there were things either taken out or things copied in from other sources. Not giving up, but perhaps you might clarify things. I will have another look in the meantime.

Comment: tq fr ur suggestions....yes, i took out code in betn which was to imply for other file types coz i oly wanna allow multiple image uploads...n i think i didnt edit it properly b4 posting!...i shall edit my question accordingly...